# Fullcalendar (jQuery Calendar) and JSON Not working

Tags: javascript, sql, json, events, fullcalendar

For some reason I can't see any event display on my Fullcalendar.

### HTML

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'calendar/json-events.php'
  });
});
```

### Json-events.php

```
<?php 
    $json = array();
    $request = "SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY id";
     try {
       $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=Roger-PC\SQLEXPRESS;dbname=calendar');
     } catch(Exception $e) {
       exit('Can't access the database.');
     }
     $result = $bdd->query($request) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
     echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

So I do have some data in my database, and still nothing shows up, I was wondering maybe there is some problem with my url from events? I tried to just put

```
events: 'events.php'
```

Still doesn't show up, then maybe my connexion to the database?

In my table I have 4 fields: Id, title, start, end

Thanks for reading!

Comment: print the json array in the console, is it empty or not? If not empty, look the values under 'start' and 'end', this date needs to be in ISO8601 format, IETF format, or a UNIX timestamp - not in millis for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So first of all I did put "console.log($result);" in my json-events.php and then in the console with F12 I tried "console.log($result); and I get this ; ReferenceError: result is not defined.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or I just can't access my json-events.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just placing json-events.php in the main folder?  Here is what my json-events.php code looks like.  My database table layout is different than yours so keep that in mind.  Note you do have to name your fields correctly... like start, end, url, color, title, description...

```
<?php
require(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/include/Database.php');
require(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/include/Common.php');

// connect to the server 
$db->connect(); 

$sql = "SELECT  e.eventid AS 'id', 
    e.title, 
    e.description, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datestart) AS 'start', 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateend) AS 'end', 
    '' AS 'allDay', 
    CONCAT('#',c.gcalcolor) AS 'color', 
    CONCAT('/clubs/',c.urlname,'/events/?',e.eventid) AS 'url'
    FROM events e
    INNER JOIN clubevents ce ON e.eventid=ce.eventid
    INNER JOIN clubs c ON ce.clubid=c.clubid";

$results = $db->fetch_array($sql);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $rows[] = $result;
}

print json_encode($rows);

?>
```